# Get list of channels with Telegram TL

Tags: telegram

I need a list of all channels that user has already joined. I found the below function:

```
channels.getChannels#0a7f6bbb id:Vector<InputChannel> = messages.Chats
```

But I couldn't understand "id: Vector<InputChannel>". If it's ID of a channel, is that mean it only return information of a single channel?! On the other hand, its return type is "messages.Chats". I really don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With messages.Dialogs we will have all dialog (Groups, Channel, and Users):

```
messages.getDialogs#191ba9c5 exclude_pinned:true offset_date:int offset_id:int offset_peer:InputPeer limit:int = messages.Dialogs;
```

This will return messages.dialogsSlice object:

```
messages.dialogsSlice#71e094f3 count:int dialogs:Vector<Dialog> messages:Vector<Message> chats:Vector<Chat> users:Vector<User> = messages.Dialogs;
```

Here "chats" is a list (vector) that contain groups and channels.