# TLSharp Fetch Group List Issue

Tags: c#, telegram, tlsharp

I can't fetch **the full list of groups**, the response returns only **new groups**

my code :

```
var dialogs = (TLDialogsSlice)await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();
                    var chats = dialogs.Chats
                      .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TLChat))
                      .Cast<TLChat>();

                    Console.WriteLine("Count : " + chats.Count());
```

i use this method :

```
public async Task<TLAbsDialogs> GetUserDialogsAsync()
        {
            var peer = new TLInputPeerChat();
            return await client.SendRequestAsync<TLAbsDialogs>(
                new TLRequestGetDialogs() { OffsetPeer = peer, Limit = int.MaxValue });
        }


var dialogs = await GetUserDialogsAsync() as TLDialogsSlice;
                    var chats = dialogs.Chats
                               .OfType<TLChat>()
                               .ToList();
                    Console.WriteLine("Count : " + chats.Count());
```

when **Limit = int.MaxValue** or **0** output is 15 groups, when **Limit = int.MinValue** output is 7 groups

but the problem **i have more than 15 groups joined on telegram** why i can't fetch all them ?

Comment: Check with Limit=100

Comment: If you are using TLDialogsSlice check if there is any slice, it means is there any limit to TLDialogsSlice, like MaxValue is 15 or something.

Comment: :( nothing about that limit but i'm sure there is something in the core need to be updated 
look at this issue it's similar : https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues/674

Comment: There should be some workaround to deal with.

Comment: yeah bro i try to do some update on the TLSharp project like changing types from int to long/decimal but o get more exceptions...

Comment: the same here but no one response :/ https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues/712

Comment: Try the code which you got cast exception earlier, and try to handle that exception, there must be some workarounds to this bug.  https://stackify.com/csharp-exception-handling-best-practices/

Comment: hey bro finally i get the full list of chats :) i update the core dll using this PR : 
https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/pull/926/files/27d680f5268fcfe4c06075999d2a4925d981bf25

Comment: Wow! finally you solved the issue with dll. It's great bro.

Comment: thank you bro for your help (y) if you want the full project TLSharp edited i can send it to you.

Comment: Currently I'm not using it, but if it's ok for you, you can include it in your answer. It might be useful for some others who are struggling with these kind of errors, which don't have much info available on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an update is here from this [PR](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/pull/926/files/27d680f5268fcfe4c06075999d2a4925d981bf25)

and the final code is :

```
var AllChats = await client.GetAllChats();
var groups = AllChats.Chats.OfType<TLChat>().ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Count : " + groups.Count());
```

Now i can get the full chats list using `GetAllChats()` method in **TLSharp.Core/TelegramClient.cs**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     var dialogs = (TLDialogs)await client.GetUserDialogsAsync() as TLDialogs;
       var chats = dialogs.Chats
                   .OfType<TLChat>()
                   .ToList();
     Console.WriteLine("Count : " + chats.Count());
```

If you want a full list of chats with messages and auxiliary data, use messages.dialogs instead of messages.dialogsSlice

If you want to return the current user dialog list, use messages.getDialogs

In your case, it is `TLDialogs`

Check the API Methods here on this link [Working with Dialogs](https://core.tlgr.org/type/messages.Dialogs)

If still some groups doesn't show in your return list, try using offset = 0 and limit = 20 , then send another messages.Dialogs request with offset 20, limit = 20. You can just set your own offset and limit.

You can find how to set offset & limit here at this [link](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues/597)

Comment: hello bro, your code will return only one group if match groupName variable, but my case i need to fetch all my group i already joins on telegram, my code returns only 15 new groups but i have more that 15, thank you for you reply bro

Comment: The same results bro :/

Comment: Returns only 15 groups i have more than 15 I don't know why ! Im confused

Comment: You have already mentioned "Chats" in your code which is a list (vector) that contains groups and channels.

Comment: Does this relate to your problem anyway https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923382/get-list-of-channels-with-telgram-tl/45486618#45486618

Comment: when i use TLDialogs instead of TLDialogSlice i get a cast exception : Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException'

Comment: yes bro i do : 

var dialogs = (TLDialogs)await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();
       var chats = dialogs.Chats
                   .OfType<TLChat>()
                   .ToList();
     Console.WriteLine("Count : " + chats.Count());
------
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException'

Comment: Add      as TLDialogs     in this code =>     var dialogs = await client.GetUserDialogsAsync() as TLDialogs; Check the updated answer.

Comment: i update my code as you do but still not i get now a NullReferenceException
there is a problem with the type of variables in the DLL i thing limit must be a long type not int

Comment: Try nullable? once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212206/discussion-between-abhishek-duppati-and-mzcatcher).